# Initialized variable not accessable inside of the class

Tags: python, oop

```
class DemoClass:
    
    def __init__(self):
       self.name = "Marko"
 
    def some_method(self):
        print(self.name)
 
    print(self.name)   # NameError: name 'self' is not defined ???
 
 
my_object = DemoClass()
```

Why does this happen? Didn't I initialize the self.name variable in the **init** method which I think it means that it should be accessable in the entire class?

Comment: When python executes your `print(self.name)` neither self nor name are available. Did you mean: `my_object.some_method()`?

Comment: You did initialise name, but it is only available in instance methods.

Comment: Under what circumstance would you want self.name to be printed?

Comment: The way `print(self.name)` is indented, means that it's part of the class `DemoClass` and the code will be executed when the interpreter initially reads the class into memory. When that happens, the variable `self.name` hasn't been defined yet (because it's defined when you make an instance of the class later).

Answer (score 1):

```
class DemoClass:
    
    def __init__(self):
       self.name = "Marko"
 
    def some_method(self):
        print(self.name)
     
      
my_object = DemoClass()

my_object.some_method()
```

do like this bro then only you can print the name.

Answer (score 0):

You call the `print()` function with a class attribute (`name`) as argument. Even though the attribute is defined when Python executes the `print()` line, the class attributes exist in the local scope of the class and are accessible only to the class members or through the class namespace (e.g. `my_object.name` in a different scope where `my_object` is defined).